# What does “The training camp in [X] was deep inside ” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

```
The training camp in Balakot was deep inside
```

Can someone please explain what the phrase above means? Here what does deep inside mean?

Comment: Reading the context, it seems to mean "deep inside Pakistan"  That is, not near the border.

Comment: @ GEdgar below is the full phrase for your reference ''The training camp in Balakot was deep inside. It’s in proper Pakistan itself, close to Abbottabad, infamous for Osama bin Laden,” says senior IAF source. This is the link for your reference. https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/iaf-jets-hit-terrorist-camp-across-loc-iaf-sources/article26371599.ece?homepage=true

Comment: To me, "deep inside" without a complement is odd unless it has already been established what it is inside.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the full context.  Comments have a tendency to get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [the full context](http://www.apnlive.com/india-news/pulwama-retribution-india-uses-iaf-first-time-1971-strike-jem-terror-camp-57575):

> The pre-dawn air strikes by the Indian Air Force (IAF) Mirage fighter jets was on a Jaish-e-Mohammed (JeM) training camp located in Balakot inside Pakistan and not the one in Pakistan Occupied Kashmir (POK), reported The Hindu quoting a senior IAF source.
>
> “The terror launch pads along the LoC were moved deep inside after the Pulwama attack. The training camp in Balakot was deep inside. It’s in proper Pakistan itself, close to Abbottabad infamous because of Osama bin Laden,” the source said on condition of anonymity.

So the meaning is clearly "deep inside Pakistan."